# fragment arguments returning NPE uriString?

Tags: android, android-fragments

What gives with this code...

I'm trying to pass data using setArguments to a fragment.

This is the code in the main activity:

```
      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      Log.d("channel0001", "videoScene");
            try{
            message = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(intent.getStringExtra("message")).nextValue();
            System.out.printf("mloqooBroadcast",message);
            String incomingScene = message.getString("url");
            Log.d("mloqooBroadcast", incomingScene);
            output = incomingScene.replaceFirst("s","");
            String sceneProvider = message.getString("sceneProvider");
            if(sceneProvider.equalsIgnoreCase("loqootv") || (sceneProvider.equalsIgnoreCase("youtubeScene"))){
                Log.d("channel0001", "youtubeScene");
                sceneProvider = message.getString("sceneProvider");
                networkName = message.getString("networkName");
                networkAvatar = message.getString("networkAvatar");
                Tag1 = message.getString("sceneTag1");
                Tag3 = message.getString("sceneTag3");
                sceneLat = message.getString("sceneLat");
                sceneLong = message.getString("sceneLong");
                args.putString("sceneProvider", message.getString("sceneProvider"));
                args.putString("url", output);
                args.putString("networkName", message.getString("networkName"));
                args.putString("networkAvatar", message.getString("networkAvatar"));
                args.putString("Tag1", message.getString("sceneTag1"));
                args.putString("Tag3", message.getString("sceneTag3"));
                args.putString("sceneLat", message.getString("sceneLat"));
                args.putString("sceneLong", message.getString("sceneLong"));
                Log.d("channel0001", networkAvatar);
                Log.d("channel0001", networkName);
                Log.d("channel0001", Tag3);
                Log.d("channel0001", Tag1);
                Log.d("channel0001", output);
              }catch(JSONException e){
                System.out.printf("fScreen.IncomingScene.Error", e);    
            }
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
            FragVideo fragVideo = new FragVideo();
            fragVideo.setArguments(args);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.pip_fragment, fragVideo, "video");
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

this is the code in the fragment:

```
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        video = (VideoView)getView().findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    Log.d("LifeCycle.Video","FirstIntent");
        String sceneUrl = args.getString("url");    
        String sceneProvider = args.getString("sceneProvider");
        String networkName = args.getString("networkName");
        String networkAvatar = args.getString("networkAvatar");
        String sceneTag1 = args.getString("Tag1");
        String sceneTag3 = args.getString("Tag3");
        String sceneLat = args.getString("sceneLat");
        String sceneLong = args.getString("sceneLong");
        //Log.d("fragVIDEO",networkName);
        //Log.v("video_url", sceneProvider);
        new video().execute(sceneUrl);
        ......
        @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(params[0]);
            publishProgress(uri);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return null;
    }
```

}

I keep getting NullPointerException: uriString errors.

```
        06-07 19:30:19.397: W/System.err(13944): java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
        06-07 19:30:19.397: W/System.err(13944):    at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:464)
        06-07 19:30:19.397: W/System.err(13944):    at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:454)
        06-07 19:30:19.397: W/System.err(13944):    at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:426)
        06-07 19:30:19.397: W/System.err(13944):    at tv.loqoo.FourthScreen.Fragments.FragVideo$video.doInBackground(FragVideo.java:183)
        06-07 19:30:19.397: W/System.err(13944):    at tv.loqoo.FourthScreen.Fragments.FragVideo$video.doInBackground(FragVideo.java:1)
        06-07 19:30:19.397: W/System.err(13944):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        06-07 19:30:19.397: W/System.err(13944):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
        06-07 19:30:19.397: W/System.err(13944):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        06-07 19:30:19.397: W/System.err(13944):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
        06-07 19:30:19.397: W/System.err(13944):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        06-07 19:30:19.397: W/System.err(13944):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        06-07 19:30:19.397: W/System.err(13944):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I know this whole flow is working because if I do this....

```
        new video().execute("url_to_some_video");
```

everything works dandy, so I know the data isn't being passed from the main activity..

Comment: post all the errors/logcat

Comment: one of the variable might be null what you are doing is correct so check or assign default value to the variables

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin added full error log

Comment: @sirvon post doInBackground(FragVideo.java:183)

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin posted but that's only speaking about no uri/url because the data isnt passing through

Comment: @Log.d the output before you put the String

Comment: did it...it comes out as the url thats trying to be passed through but without the s in https.